# Node.js destroying Constant

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm reinventing the wheel and building an LED display matrix with a raspberry Pi, Node.js v18.18 and a Hub75 LED matrix.  There is a little web app that allow you to enter the text and it is sent to the matrix for display.  Initially it works exactly as expected. Website shows up, you can enter text, and it is displayed.  After about 10 seconds from the first message being entered, a message is sent to console:

```
Server is running on port 8080
Received text: Hello
Destroying font
Received text: World
```

The web server still works, but text is not displayed on the matrix.  I'm assuming it is because the font is destroyed.  My belief is that is is being destroyed with the socket connection expiring.  However, I can't figure out why and how it is destroying a constant that is in use and declared outside the scope of the socket.

I'm new to node.js and it is a significant shift from Python. Any insight or help is much appreciated.

App.js

```
coconst express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const { Font, LedMatrix, LedMatrixUtils } = require('rpi-led-matrix');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

// Define your matrix configuration
const matrixOptions = {
  ...LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions(),
  rows: 32,
  cols: 64,
  chainLength: 2,
  parallel: 1,
  brightness: 100,
  hardwareMapping: 'Adafruit-hat-pwm',
};

// Font
const font = new Font('5x7', __dirname + '/node_modules/rpi-led-matrix/fonts/5x7.bdf');

const runtimeOptions = LedMatrix.defaultRuntimeOptions();
const matrix = new LedMatrix(matrixOptions, runtimeOptions);


matrix
    .clear()
    .brightness(100)
    .fgColor(0x00adff)
    .drawRect(0, 0, 63, 31)
    .font(font)
    .fgColor(0xff0000)
    .drawText('Hello', 1, 1)
    .drawText('World', 1, 8)
    .sync();

app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('/index.html');
});


app.post('/display', (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  io.emit('display_text', text);

  // Clear the matrix
  matrix.clear();




});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('display_text', (text) => {
    // You can control the matrix here
    // For simplicity, we'll just log the text
    console.log('Received text:', text);
    matrix.clear();
    matrix.drawText(text, 1, 1);
    matrix.sync();
  });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 8080');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LED Matrix Text Display</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>LED Matrix Text Display</h1>
  <form action="/display" method="POST">
    <label for="text">Enter text:</label>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text">
    <button type="submit">Display Text</button>
  </form>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io();

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const text = document.querySelector('#text').value;
      socket.emit('display_text', text);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The message comes from [the destructor of the Font class in a native module written in C++](https://github.com/alexeden/rpi-led-matrix/blob/e1423a58b42db92cd2e32f7decf356b3b620429b/src/font.addon.cc#L35C16-L35C21). I don't see _why_ that destructor would be called, but perhaps this tidbit can help someone else.